# valid regex for detection of <title> tag that may have a id or a class attribute

Tags: php, regex, facebook

REGEX

```
 /<title( *)((id|class)(=\")(.*)(\"))?>(.*)<\/title>/i
```

the above regex is to detect the below forms of the title tag

```
<title id="titleid">Test</title>
<title class="titleclass">Test</title>
<title>Test</title>
```

the reason is that im creating a link extractor like fb but while testing the script with the link `https://www.facebook.com` i noticed that its not picking up the title tag from fb hence i inspected their code and found that their title tag has a id attribute hence i want to create a regex for a title attribute that may or may not have a additional attribute

But is the regex a valid one

Comment: why even care about the class/id? `/<title[^>]*>(.*)<\/title>/is` will always find the title tag, regardless of attributes. Unless you need the id/class for some reason. But I would still suggest using a simpler regex like this and parsing those out afterwards.

Comment: We need more information, what do you use to download the contents of [Facebook](http://facebook.com) and what function(s) are you using for your regular expressions.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn `<title[^>]*?>(.*)</title>/is` does not work i get this error `preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier 't'`

Comment: oh, escape the forward slash in `</title>`. I'm also missing the starting slash. I edited my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.documentElement.innerHTML.match(/<title( *)((id|class)(=\")(.*)(\"))?>(.*)<\/title>/i)` works for me on [Facebook](http://facebook.com)...I get this response in Chrome:

```
[
  "<title id="pageTitle">Welcome to Facebook - Log In, Sign Up or Learn More</title>",
  " ",
  "id="pageTitle"",
  "id",
  "="",
  "pageTitle",
  """,
  "Welcome to Facebook - Log In, Sign Up or Learn More"
]
```

Why not avoid regular expressions altogether with [`.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName):

```
var titleElement = document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0];
// <title id="pageTitle">Welcome to Facebook - Log In, Sign Up or Learn More</title>
titleElement.id; // pageTitle
titleElement.className; // null
```

Or with a pure [jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

```
var $title = $('title');
```

Comment: sorry its a regex for php please edfit ur answer

Comment: Works just the same in PHP, can we see your example PHP code?

Answer (score 1):

One problem can be using `'` other than `"`:

```
<title id='someID'>Another Title</title>
```

Also what if they used both a `class` and `id`? Would you want to pick that up? What about other attributes as well? Also we don't need to use regular expressions to do this, that is if you want any `<title>` tag, you can search by the `DOM`. Using `getElementsByTagName`. Here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php